# SwiftUI: How to enable playing audio in background of the app, after sheet disappear?

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, background, swiftui

I am making streaming audio app. I've already created audio player getting the data from firestore as an appearing sheet, but when it disappears audio stops. I am looking for solution how to enable listening it while using app, even if user close the audio player sheet.

Here's the code of upcoming sheet:

```
struct PodcastPlayerView : View {

@State var album : Album
@State var song : Song



@State var player = AVPlayer()

@State var isPlaying : Bool = false


var body: some View{
    ZStack{
        Color.white
        VStack{
            Image(song.image)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 350, height: 350, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(radius: 20)
                .padding(30)
            
            Text(song.songName)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text(song.artist)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Spacer()
            AudioPlayerControlsView2(player: player,
                                     timeObserver2: PlayerTimeObserver2(player: player),
                                     durationObserver2: PlayerDurationObserver2(player: player),
                                     itemObserver2: PlayerItemObserver2(player: player))
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: self.previous, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "backward.end.fill")
                        .resizable()
                }).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center).foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                Spacer()
                Button(action: self.playPause, label: {
                    Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "pause.circle.fill" : "play.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                }).frame(width: 55, height: 55, alignment: .center).foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                Spacer()
                Button(action: self.next, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "forward.end.fill")
                        .resizable()
                }).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center).foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }.onAppear(){
            playSong()
        }
    }
}


func playSong(){
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: self.song.file)
    storage.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }else{
            
            do{
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            }
            catch{
                // report for an error
            }
        
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: url!))
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```